# Sessions in c# with HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, session-variables

Hello How I can recover the user id with sessions in c# ?

I researched and the best way is using HttpContext.Current.Session but I don't know how to.

Comment: are you using asp.net

Comment: Did you do any research on how to use session in web application?

Comment: Generally speaking you should get your user ID from the principal that is assigned to the current thread, often as the result of request authentication, drawn from an encrypted token, e.g. the forms authentication ticket or OAuth. Using just session-based authentication is not very secure.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, you need to first set the session value using a specific key, assuming you have two pages. In page1 you set the session that has key "User"to value "test1"

```
Session["User"] = "test1" ;
```

Then, you can get this value from anywhere, as example in page2 you want to get the value, you use the same key "User" since its a collection of key-value pairs.

```
   var mySessionValue =  Session["User"];
```

In case you are storing objects or any other types you need to cast it to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET, you can try

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```